# Управление обновлением текущего местоположения. Google Maps. Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-service

Я получаю данные о моём местоположении в активности. Исходя из этого значения я могу построить, например, маркеры на карте. 
Затем я нажимаю на кнопку и запускаю сервис, который будет считать пройденное расстояние (и в нём мне нужно будет тоже реализовать LocationListener).

Я думал запускать 1 сервис (bind сразу в OnCreate() активности и stop в onDestroy() активности), который будет отдавать мне изменения местоположения и далее на основе этих значений считать пройденное расстояние. Но как поступить, если я не считаю ещё расстояние, то в onStop() нужно бы отписаться от обновлений моего местоположения.

Возможно, есть совсем другой более рациональный способ решения этой задачки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:
1. Привязать сервис к активити с помощью `Binder` и запускать сервис при старте активити или по нажатию кнопки.
2. Реализовать `LocationListener` в сервисе и отдавать данные в активити, например через `Intent`.
3. В активити принимать данные и отображать на карте.
4. Останавливать сервис когда нужно, тогда данные местоположение не будет определяться и т.д.

**ИЛИ:**
не реализовывать сервис вообще, тогда активити будет уходить в бекграунд при onStop() методе, результат будет тот же

Comment: вот я сделал с помощью Binder. данные то я получаю, но как в этом случае отписаться от прослушивания изменений местоположения? Что бы при свернутом приложении не ело батарею зря

Comment: @itslayo, обновил ответ